# What changed from PostgreSQL 8.3 to 9.2 in regex matching?

Tags: regex, postgresql

If I run this query:

```
SELECT 'Via Orologio 122 A' SIMILAR TO '(Strada|Via) % [0-9]+( [A-Z])?';
```

I expect to get TRUE. Version 9.1.8 of postgreSQL returns the expected value, but in version 8.3 it returns FALSE. I think that the problem is the final question mark. In fact, the query:

```
SELECT 'Via Orologio 122 A' SIMILAR TO '(Strada|Via) % [0-9]+( [A-Z])';
```

Returns TRUE in both versions.

Anyone knows which is the difference between the two versions?

Comment: `SIMILAR TO` doesn't use proper regex, it uses a bastardised form specified by the SQL standard. PostgreSQL only supports it because the standard says it should. Use the `~` operator where simple `LIKE` is not sufficient. As for what changed: Looks like a bugfix in "similar to" to me, but you should check the relnotes and git history for details.

Comment: Actually, [Postgres rewrites `SIMILAR TO` to regular expressions internally](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions-in-postgresql/10696#10696). In other words: for every `SIMILAR TO`, there is at least one `~` expression that's faster. *If* you can `LIKE` instead, that's probably even faster.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thanks, I was unclear. I should've said "Doesn't use normal regular expression syntax"; I was referring to the weird pseudo-regex syntax that's neither POSIX regex nor PCRE rather than the execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [changelog of 8.3.2](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/release-8-3-2.html):

> Fix a corner case in regular-expression substring matching
>   `(substring(string from pattern))` (Tom)
>   The problem occurs when there
>   is a match to the pattern overall but the user has specified a
>   parenthesized subexpression and that subexpression hasn't got a match.
>   An example is `substring('foo' from 'foo(bar)?')`. This should return
>   NULL, since `(bar)` isn't matched, but it was mistakenly returning the
>   whole-pattern match instead (ie, `foo`)

Comment: Very kind of you to dive through the relnotes. I commented rather than answered precisely because I didn't really want do do the OP's RTFMing for them.

Comment: It's very nice to provide a source. But it's not so nice to misquote - or not quote at all. You did both. This is from the changelog of 8.3.2.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter 8.3.2 hasn't been released ever so first occurence of this path is in 8.3.3

Comment: @LadislavDANKO: That's interesting to know, but when I tried to find your quote, my attempt was futile. The point is to quote properly and add a link so people can look it up.

Answer (score 1):

The drop-in replacement using a regular expression with (`~`) would be:

```
SELECT 'Via Orologio 122 A' ~ '^(?:(?:Strada|Via) .* [0-9]+(?: [A-Z])?)$'
```

- left-anchored and right-anchored
- with `*`, not `+`
- non-capturing parentheses

Hint:
You can let Postgres translate `SIMILAR TO` expressions for you with the [technique outlined in this related answer on dba.SE.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)

Answer (score 0):

Following Craig Ringer's advice, changing to:

```
SELECT 'Via Orologio 122 A' ~ '(Strada|Via) .+ [0-9]+( [A-Z])?';
```

solved the problem. '~' seems to be a definitely better solution than 'SIMILAR TO'